# Testing and Embedding Code - HTML/JS/CSS “Codepen/JSFiddle”

Tags: html, cms, css

I'm working on creating iFrames for a company and looking to embed custom charts within our iFrame creation platform. I'm a big fan of "a certain JS library" and its responsive charts, so I created a proof of concept in Codepen to showcase its functionality. Because this is a larger company, chances are getting this code approved after audits... it's going to be a lengthy process.

Are there online coding environments like CodePen (free or paid) allowing you to create standalone, embed-able HTML/CSS/JS experiences/productions? I'm thinking of adding as an embed within our audited/approved iFrame service to avoid delay/rejection.